# Broken Python virtualenvwrapper

Tags: virtualenvwrapper

I seem to have broken virtualenvwrapper while trying to upgrade Python 3 from 3.4.1 to the current version.  Whenever I run "workon xxx", I get the following error:

`usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')`

Background:

I have Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.1 installed on my Mac workstation (OSX 10.8.5).  I also have virtualenvwrapper running with many different environments - some using 2.7 and other 3.4.  Virtualenvwrapper was installed under 3.4.

I just attempted to upgrade Python 3.4.1 to the latest version by running "brew install python3".  This installed 3.4.2, but failed to fully complete, saying it was unable to create a few necessary symlinks, and to run "brew link --overwrite python3", which I did.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it, but it would be great to get some feedback / confirmation.

From the error message, I am guessing that the Python3 virtualenvwrapper module had gotten blown away (or symlinked away).  I found that pip can be forced to run from to run from a particular Python version using the syntax: `pipV.V <command>`.  That is, to run pip against Python 3.4: `$ pip3.4 freeze`, for example.

Pip complained about being out of date, so here's all the steps I took to seemingly repair the problem:

`$ sudo pip3.4 install --upgrade pip
$ pip3.4 freeze 
   (returned nothing, and pip no longer complained about being out of date)
$ sudo pip3.4 install virtualenvwrapper`

Now "workon xxx" no longer complains, and appears to be functioning properly...